# Run product specific .exe file on web server

Tags: wordpress, usb, exe

I have a client that has a .exe file used to program a water conservation device via USB. He wants to have them connect the device and then go to the website to program it via the .exe file. I am not sure this is possible and that the consumer should just download the .exe. However, that would limit usage to PC and not Mac (unless they are Mac-Savvy and can run a PC emulator like Bootcamp etc.)
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but it is definitely not recommended, as this can cause major secure risks and to have open access to `.exe` files can mean serious implications for your server.

First off, your server needs to be running on a windows ISS server. I guess you already are as you understand that the file will only run on a windows machine.

Next you need to determine what language you are going to access the file with. You can use `ASP.Net` or `PHP`.

I dont know anything about `ASP.Net` and so the way i would do it in `PHP` is to run it using the `exec()` functions which allows for the execution of files on the server.

You would need to direct the function to the `.exe` file.

Im not exactly sure what the file does or how you intend to use it as i believe it that you will only get a text return instead of a GUI interface.

Read more about the exec function [HERE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)